# Exact sequence of tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here is a quotation of a book:

> **Proposition 3.7.1.** If $0 \rightarrow J \rightarrow A \rightarrow (A/J)\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence, then for every $B$, the natural sequence
>   $$0 \rightarrow J\otimes_{max} B \rightarrow A\otimes_{max} B \rightarrow(A/J)\otimes_{max}B\rightarrow 0$$
>   is also exact. (Here, $A$ is a C*-algebra and $J$ is a C*-subalgebra, I think.)

In order to prove the conclusion, of course, we need to show $J\otimes_{max} B \rightarrow A\otimes_{max} B$ is injective and $A\otimes_{max} B \rightarrow(A/J)\otimes_{max}B$ is surjective. However, I can understand the proof of this proposition.

**In the proof, the author say "$J\otimes_{max} B \rightarrow A\otimes_{max} B$ is injective follows from Corollary 3.6.4, while $A\otimes_{max} B \rightarrow(A/J)\otimes_{max}B$ is surjective thanks to the fact that $^{*}$-homomorphisms of C$^{*}$-algebras always have closed range." I can not understand this explaination:**

1. The $J$, here, is a hereditary subalgebra of $A$?
2. How to use "C*-algebra always have closed range" to illustrate the surjectivity?

Here is so called **Corollary 3.6.4.**

**Corollary 3.6.4.** If $A\subset B$ is hereditary subalgebra, then for every $C$ we have a natural inclusion
$$A\otimes_{max} C\subset B\otimes_{max} C.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $J$ is a closed two-sided ideal of $A$. This is necessary in order for $A/J$ to be a $C^*$-algebra. Such an ideal is a hereditary subalgebra, so we can apply Corollary 3.6.4.

Working with the algebraic tensor products shows that the *-homomorphism from $A \otimes_{max} B$ to $(A/J) \otimes_{max} B$ has dense range. As the range is also closed, it must be all of $(A/J) \otimes_{max} B$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I ignore $J$ is a closed two-sided ideal. Thanks Tom.